# To Create Protovis Sunburst charts : Python script to create dataset in json format (or) Parent - Child json

Tags: python, json, protovis, sunburst-diagram

Help!!! As a biologist I am just interested in visualizing and displaying my data and I am very new to programming. Here I have a set of data in a excel file, which looks like this-

I guess it's very perfect to display my data set using [Sunburst](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/sunburst.html) chart in Protovis.

But I have stuck with preparing the data, which has to be in json format. If you notice that the structure of the data is hierarchical (Parent - Child hierarchy). Being not so good in programming (just know a little bit of Python) it's difficult to go ahead.

**I need a python script which can read my excel file and generate a json as specified above.**

My excel data file has columns named L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, GENE_NAMES having data and there is a parent and child relationship. L1 is Parent to L2 and L2 is parent to L3, so on...

- L1 (PARENT) - L2 (CHILD)
- L2 (PARENT) - L3 (CHILD)
- L3 (PARENT) - L4 (CHILD)
- L4 (PARENT) - L5 (CHILD)
- L5 (PARENT) - GENE_NAME (CHILD)

Hope I can get my data set visualized in the above format. But I should have my data-set in the json format specified in [here](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/sunburst.html)

Any sort of help appreciated.

Comment: is there any specific reason to use java-script based visualization?

Comment: not really, but I taught that this is the best and easiest way for representing data. And I don't know any other way to do it.
One more thing is, the size of the data too big to represent in any other formats

Comment: it can be done very easily with other libraries. . and one more thing. .does your output chart is fixed. .that 'Sun burst'. .or any chart which can represent parent-child relationships. .but similar to that 'Sun burst'

Comment: no, not really! any sort of chart is fine. My idea behind this is, more data can be easily represented radially without any fuss. As said I have a huge data set, so that's the only reason to use Sunbursts-- in which the center of the circle will be main parent which then divides into children over the periphery.

Answer (score 0):

use [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) to represent such graphs(where parent-child relationship is present).. . by using it; your code remains in the python.. .
example:

http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/lanl_routes.html